# method for getting function from power series/perturbation series

Tags: taylor-series, tag-removed

is there any definite method or algorithm,software to get exact function or expression from series.e.g  we get series solution of differential equation and we want exact expression rather than approximation series ?

Comment: Usually I do this the other way around.  I have a power series, and want its sum, so if I can find a DE it satisfies, then solve the DE to get the result!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases yes, see:

http://www.reduce-algebra.com/docs/qsum.pdf

and references therein...

**EDIT** A canonical reference is Petkovsek-Zeiberger's A=B.

Comment: More stuff in Wilf's book *generatingfunctionology*